# How can I save text in custom font to a .txt/.png/.pdf file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem: How can I save text with custom font* from a textarea into a file with the same custom font and not allow font conversion to the default system font?

I have my custom font in a .ttf file that I have set using CSS. I have also created a textarea using HTML with a keyboard that displays the characters in my custom font. I want to save the text in the custom font into a file. This file can be a .txt, .png, .pdf, or anything that would permit this custom font to be saved. I am aware that character conversion is the default one when I save the text (the default font is the system font here). I have looked into a lot of options (really!) for this and none seem to work when it comes to saving the "new text" in a file.

*Custom font here does not belong to one of the font families already available. I have converted the characters into the required font and saved them into a ".ttf".

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function saveTextAsFile() {
        var text = document.getElementById("write").value;
        //var text = document.getElementById('<span style="font-family:myFont">write</span>').value
        // document.getElementById("write").style.fontFamily =  "myFont";
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
        var fileName = "NewFile.txt";
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Hidden Link";
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="harlow">
    <textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    .
    .
    . (all the keyboard keys as a list go here)
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
   @font-face {
     font-family: "myFont";
     src: url("../font/myFont.ttf") format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../font/myFont.ttf') format('woff2'),
         url('../font/myFont.ttf') format('woff'), 
         url('../font/myFont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('../font/myFont.ttf') format('svg'); 
     font-display: optional;
   }
   .harlow {
     font-family: "myFont";
   }
```

As you can see, I am saving the text as a Blob. If there is another/better way of doing this, I would appreciate the suggestion! I am able to see the saved text as regular English characters (the custom font does not have English characters - just to be clear).

EDIT: I'm trying to develop something for the long term here. So I want to minimize the work an end-user has to do and try to put everything in my code. I'm looking for a solution that would fit this!

EDIT2: I have added my solution in the comment below.

Comment: You mean you save the data as a NewFile.txt file (am I correct) ?

Comment: .txt text files do not support custom fonts. For pdfs, use pdf.js, for png, use canvas.

Comment: @KenLee : yes, save the data (but using my Font family font) as a .txt file.

Comment: @John : You mean save it as "NewFile.pdf.js"?! I don't think I understood the suggestion, sorry.

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it and it is using docx.js and Blobs. I have only mentioned the main JS code for this:

```
const doc = new docx.Document();
var x = document.getElementById('write').value;

new docx.Paragraph({
    children: [
        new docx.TextRun({
            text: x,
            font: {name: "myFont",},
        }),
    ],
}),
```

Paragraph is a child of addSection(). Using docx.Packer, write to Blob. Hope this helps anyone having a similar problem!